# Kubernetes: cert-manager certificate is keep in pending state

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, lets-encrypt, cert-manager

I have installed cert-manager 0.12.0 for SSL certificate.

My Issuer file is

```
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1alpha2
kind: ClusterIssuer
metadata:
  name: letsencrypt-prod
spec:
  acme:
    server: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    email: my@email.com
    privateKeySecretRef:
      name: letsencrypt-prod
    http01: {}
```

My certificate file

```
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1alpha2
kind: Certificate
metadata:
  name: tls-secret
spec:
  secretName: tls-secret-prod
  dnsNames:
  - mydomain.com
  acme:
    config:
    - http01:
        ingressClass: nginx
      domains:
      - mydomain.com
  issuerRef:
    name: letsencrypt-prod
    kind: ClusterIssuer
```

Ingress configuration is

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: cms
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-prod
    kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - mydomain.com
    secretName: tls-secret-prod
  rules:
  - host: mydomain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: apostrophe
          servicePort: 80
        path: /
```

But still, SSL certificated is not valid. And Common name is “Kubernetes Ingress Controller Fake Certificate”.

The following result to show orders and challenges

```
kubectl get orders, challenges -o wide
NAME                                                  STATE     DOMAIN            REASON                                                                                                        AGE
challenge.certmanager.k8s.io/tls-secret-155743219-0   pending   mydomain.com   pods "cm-acme-http-solver-gk2zx" is forbidden: minimum cpu usage per Container is 100m, but request is 10m.   26m
```

I have updated the resources limit the range and reinstalled cert-manager with helm. I am still getting this error. 
I am not sure what goes wrong or show how to fix this.

Please let me know if you need anything. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The problem lays in cpu limits defined for specific pod. 
You have to change minimum CPU limit in deployment configuration file. As you can see pod  (**cm-acme-http-solver**) is requesting  **100m** CPU usage while minimum CPU usage defined for specific pod is *10m**. So change CPU limits in deployment configuration file from **100m** to **10m** or less or you can also increase CPU requests.

Take a look here: [cert-manager-kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/manage-resources/cpu-constraint-namespace/), [pod-min-cpu-request](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/manage-resources/cpu-constraint-namespace/#attempt-to-create-a-pod-that-does-not-meet-the-minimum-cpu-request).

Useful article: [resources-limits-kubernetes](https://medium.com/@betz.mark/understanding-resource-limits-in-kubernetes-cpu-time-9eff74d3161b).